# Images become smaller after updating

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I made a custom cell with 50x50 size UIImageView object.
When I starting the application and it's downloading images with the same size from server all of them displaying with right sizes. 
But then I make a tap in cell or scrolling back cells starting update and all pictures become smaller. What am I doing wrong?
Placeholders have also 50x50 size and their size is right after update.

```css
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
static NSString *identifier = @"NTFriendsListCellID";
    
NTFriendsListCell *cell = 
[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = 
[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.photoView.bounds];
    
NTFriend *friend = [self.friends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
__weak UITableViewCell *weakCell = cell;
    
[cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:friend.photoURLRequest
               
      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unknown.png"]
               
      success:^(NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request, 
      NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, UIImage * _Nonnull image) {
               
               weakCell.imageView.image = image;
               
      }
      failure:nil   
];
     
return cell;
```

Screenshot before update:

[image: Before update]

Screenshot after update:

[image: After update]

Comment: Whats the actual size of the image that you are loading?

Comment: Its seems like the issue is because of you are not properly set the `contentmode` of `image view`. Please try out this
`cell.imageView .contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit`

Comment: Image size equals 50x50. I tried to set contentMode but it doesn't work.